# Testing web service objects against xsd

Tags: java, web-services

I have a task to write tests for web services. But the test is just to validate our objects against the xsd file.
The test steps are: 
Create a Schema object from our xsd. Then take the validator from schema and validate our object against it.
My questions:

- What is the purpose of this test? Is it to prevent someone from changing the object structure?
- Should all objects described in the xsd be tested this way? I get a javax.xml.bind.MarshalException (unable to marshal type 'classname' as an element because it is missing an `@XmlRootElement` annotation) when attempting to test objects that don't have `@XmlRootElement` annotation.

Where can I read more these types of tests and how are they called?

Comment: You should not test individual XML snippets but an XML representing the entire service payload. Then, vary the XML with errors here and there and everywhere and validate each variation.

Comment: The entire service payload would be a root element?

Comment: Hopefully, yes. Look into the schema.xsd and search for `<xs:element>...` not contained in any type definition.

Comment: Ok, some schemas have these elements and some dont. So for all schemas that have <xs:element> outside type definitions, these elements should be tested, and for the schemas that don't I should decide which elements to test?

Comment: The schemas without a root element: are they being included from other schemas?

Comment: It is always possible to wrap any object of class T in a JAXBElement<T> and it should be possible to marshal that.

Comment: No, they are directly in the wsdl :
`<types>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://serviceName/service?wsdl">
<xsd:complexType name = "xx">
more complex type definitions...
</types>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to test is to use XML files representing the entire service payload. Then, vary the XML with errors here and there and everywhere and validate each variation.

Another approach is to create subelements and marshal them using

```
<T> JAXBElement<T> wrap( String ns, String tag, T o ){
    QName qtag = new QName( ns, tag );
    Class<?> clazz = o.getClass();
    @SuppressWarnings( "unchecked" )
    JAXBElement<T> jbe = new JAXBElement( qtag, clazz, o );
    return jbe;
}

JAXBElement<Foo> jbe = wrap( "/some/ns", "aFoo", new Foo() );
m.marshal( jbe,... );
```

and pass the resulting XML data to the validation.

Answer (score 0):

I think the IT is better than UT to test web service.
You can use some IT framework like SOAPUI or Robot Framework to achive that.

For the missing @XmlRootElement issue. You can create a class with @XmlRootElement and extends to the class which you want to test, and do marshal on this class.

```
@XmlRootElement
public class ClassRoot extends ClassYouWantTest {

}
```